# Finding deviation of coordinates placed on boundaries of a rectilinear shape

Tags: statistics, polygon, scatter-plot, computational-geometry, coordinate-systems

I have elements placed on boundary of a rectilinear shape as depicted in the diagram. The intention is to find a metric (like for e.g. avg, std. deviation) which gives me how well the elements are clubbed together or separated throughout (as a whole for orange colors - not per line grouping) and the factor by which each elements loosely/strongly follows the grouping?

Ideally std. deviation would have done the job which provides the factor (x times) deviating from the mean (beautifully explained here: [std-dev](https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/standard-deviation.html#:%7E:text=The%20Standard%20Deviation%20is%20a%20measure%20of%20how%20spread%20out%20numbers%20are.&text=The%20formula%20is%20easy%3A%20it,square%20root%20of%20the%20Variance.))  but in this case std. deviation is a not a good metric to find grouping since the elements are not fundamentally meant to follow a center.

The data provided are the coordinates of the elements (orange one) : (x1,y1),(x2,y2),(x3,y3)....(xn,yn) and the coordinates of the rectilinear shape.

[image: orange elements placed along the boundary]

Comment: On the picture, there are 10 yellow points annotated. In the explanation, you mention 4 orange points !? What can we do with this mess ?

Comment: Your "matric" means metric, right? Can this metric be a linear distance between points, taken along polygon edges? Only problem here that you'll have two distances for each pair of points

Comment: @HEKTO - fixed the typo

Answer (score 0):

Compute the Euclidean distances between the points and the closest lines. Then consider either the mean distance or the root-mean-squared distance. (Zero in case of perfect alignment.)

Comment: since the intention is to find grouping as a whole for orange points - not per line - taking euclidean distance to closest lines will provide more optimistic value than desired.

Comment: @kil47: I disagree (or I don't understand your post).

Comment: computing Euclidean distance itself is the wrong starting point . Since the intention is to find grouping along rectilinear  line - maybe manhattan distance would be a good starting point